# Why would Dlib compile 8000+ functions?

Tags: c++, opencv, dlib

I am using `Dlib` and `OpenCV` with `C++` `Without CMake`on `Visual Studio 2015` and I have tried the `face_landmark_detection_ex` example to detect faces by using the laptop camera and it works fine. but I wonder why `Dlib` is saying: `164 of 8616 functions ( 1.9%) were compiled, the rest were copied from previous compilation.`

I think that example is very simple and does not require 8000+ function to work, I also wonder why it needs 57 Folders and 73 `Header Files` from the library.

The dependency hierarchy is not clear at all from the documentation on the Dlib's official website.

Note: I have added `source.cpp` file to my project because i was getting `Linker Error`, this could be referenced to:

> In most cases, to use this library all you have to do is extract it
>   somewhere, make sure the folder containing the dlib folder is in your
>   include path, and finally add dlib/all/source.cpp to your project. It
>   is worth noting that most of dlib is "header-only" which means that,
>   in many cases, you don't actually have to build dlib/all/source.cpp
>   into your application. So if you don't get linker errors when you
>   exclude dlib/all/source.cpp from your project then you don't need it.

**Modified Source.cpp:**

```
#include "../base64/base64_kernel_1.cpp"
#include "../entropy_decoder/entropy_decoder_kernel_2.cpp"
#include "../tokenizer/tokenizer_kernel_1.cpp"
#include "../unicode/unicode.cpp"
#include "../dir_nav/dir_nav_kernel_1.cpp"
#include "../logger/logger_kernel_1.cpp"
#include "../misc_api/misc_api_kernel_1.cpp"
#include "../threads/threaded_object_extension.cpp"
#include "../threads/threads_kernel_1.cpp"
#include "../threads/threads_kernel_shared.cpp"
#include "../timer/timer.cpp"

#include "../gui_widgets/fonts.cpp"
#include "../gui_widgets/widgets.cpp"
#include "../gui_widgets/drawable.cpp"
#include "../gui_widgets/canvas_drawing.cpp"
#include "../gui_widgets/style.cpp"
#include "../gui_widgets/base_widgets.cpp"
#include "../gui_core/gui_core_kernel_1.cpp"
```

[image]

Comment: Including CPP files is not recommended and could be the cause of your problem. When you `#include` a file, the file is effectively pasted into  your file. If you include a cpp file, then all of the definitions in that cpp file are now part of your file. If that is 8000+ functions, when, you asked for it. By convention, cpp files are compiled once and then linked in as needed. h and hpp files are included.

Comment: And how to reset compilation so that files which are now needed are available to be deleted without causing errors? Because the problem now is when I try to remove an '#include' line it causes errors.

Comment: dlib probably has a .lib file that you can link in. If not, you should make  the.lib file ([Should be instructions at dlib's site](http://dlib.net/compile.html)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to use Dlib - via CMake. [There is small tutorial how to include dlib in your project with CMake](https://github.com/davisking/dlib/blob/master/examples/CMakeLists.txt)

Another way with CMake - you can compile Dlib library and use result binary (.lib) in your project. To produce .lib file you can use this commands from Visual Studio Developer Command prompt (from dlib folder):

```
md build
cd build
cmake .. -G"Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=c:/where/to/put/release/library
cmake --build . --target install --config Release
```

After compilation is finished you will have .lib and headers in target directory. And if you want to *Debug* your program - you should compile and install dlib again into *different directory*:

```
cmake .. -G"Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=c:/where/to/put/debug/library
cmake --build . --target install --config Debug
```

This will make you debug binaries. Next in your CMake-based application project you can write this lines:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
find_package(dlib REQUIRED)
add_executable(example example.cpp)
target_link_libraries(example dlib::dlib)
```

And you can compile this application with

```
md build
cd build
cmake .. -G"Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=c:/where/to/put/release/library
cmake --build . --target install --config Release
```

And Debug  version:

```
md build
cd build
cmake .. -G"Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=c:/where/to/put/debug/library
cmake --build . --target install --config Debug
```

Please note here that when compiling Dlib you are using *CMAKE_**INSTALL**_PREFIX* - this is where to put library and when compiling your project, you are using *CMAKE_**PREFIX**_PATH* - where to search Dlib

As you can see here - there are a lot of steps and you can get errors on each stage, **so you can simply drop "all/source.cpp" in your project** (as you already done) - and thats all, it works. With all/source way you do not need to think in different compilation modes (Debug/Release), architectures (x86/x64), runtime linking (Shared/Static/Multithreaded...), different compilers - all of this options require separate dlib installation

If you will try to use CMake and if you will get some errors - just read CMake's output, there are a lot of details in it. And this way require some experience on using CMake, you can get documentation [here](http://www.cmake.org)

So answering your main question - why compile 8000 functions - this is the price of not thinking about different compilation modes. And yes, this is only Visual Studio Specific. On Linux machines - you need only one installation